# Echo is off (batch script)

Tags: batch-file

This is my script (it put out ip from ipconfig)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%A in ('ipconfig^|find "IP"^|find ":10."') do set ip==%%B
set "ipaddress=%ip:~1%"
set "ipk=%ipaddress:~1,-2%"
echo %ipk%
```

What I get is: Echo is off

Comment: That means that the content of the variable `%ipk%` is empty

Comment: Then how I can build it better? I get 10.0.50.12 from this and need to cut last 2 chars to show me only 10.0.50.

Comment: Pretty sure you do not get any output from the `FOR` command because the strings you are using are not finding anything.  You need a space in your search string after the colon.

Comment: Thx for help @Squashman

Comment: `set ip==...` is the wrong syntax, it should be `set ip=%%B`. But you should add some `echo` statements to see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't be sure that the last part of the ip address is a 2 digits number, It can be anything from 1 to 254, so cutting the the last 2 chars may not give you the right result.

Fortunately for this case, because the ip addresses are separated by `.` they can treated like file name extensions by the `FOR` modifiers.

And by using `findstr` (with regex search terms) instead of `find` for searching the ip address you can reduce the number of pipes from 2 to 1.

```
@echo off
set "ipk=IP_NOT_FOUND"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('ipconfig^|findstr /IRC:"IPv4.*: *10\."') do set "ipk=%%~nA."
set "ipk=%ipk: =%"
echo %ipk%
pause
```

However it is not clear what exactly `ipk` is representing, If you meant to display the network address, then this will most probably the wrong way to do it, because the network address depends of the value of the subnet mask which must be obtained separately and performing calculations with both the ipaddress and subnet mask to obtain the correct network address.

But this is out of scope of your question so I leave it as is.

And You should be aware that if there is more than one network adapter with `10.` ip address then this will return the ip address of the last enumerated adapter.

**Interpretation of the `findstr` regex term:** `"IPv4.*: *10\."`
`IPv4` A line which contains the string "IPv4" (case insensitive because the `/I` switch)
`.*:` followed by zero or more of any character, followed by a colon `:`
`*10\.` followed by zero or more spaces, followed by `10.` and the rest of the line if any.

Comment: As a slight modification to the above, the following should work similarly should you be unaware of the value of the first, _or any other_, octet prior to running the script: you should be able to do it in one line: `@Set "ipk=" & For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=:" %%A In ('IPConfig^|Find "IPv4"') Do @For %%B In (%%A) Do @Set "ipk=%%~nB."`. You could then follow this up with `@If Not Defined ipk …` as necessary, _where `Not` could be omitted depending upon the script requirements_.

Comment: It always show `IP_NOT_FOUND`. I have this line with IP that I changed: `Adres IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.102.222`

Comment: @fosfik, Are you using a non English version of windows? is that the exact line that you see in the `ipconfig` output? `Adres IPv4. . .` starting with the word `Adres`? Please replace the `findstr` regex with this one `"^.*IPv4.*: *10\."` and try again. If that works please inform me to update the answer accordingly. I just replaced the space between `^` and `*` by a `.` which means any number of any characters before `IPv4`

Comment: @sst, it depends from computer to which I connect at this moment with psexec, few are with Polish language. Now it works great. Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your network range might eventually expand to other IP ranges so I thought I would add another option where you would not have to hard code your starting range. So this is more of an extension to your query.

Here I just take the subnet configured, get the IP in that range and match to your IP, then echo it. It does not require you to hard code the IP's beginning range:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims={,}" %%a in ('"wmic nicconfig where IPEnabled="True" get DefaultIPGateway /value | find "I" "') do set gate_test=%%~a
set gate_test=!gate_test: =!
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=^." %%i in ("!gate_test!") do set range=%%i.%%j
    for /f "delims=:" %%l in ('ipconfig ^| findstr IPv4') do (
      set ip=%%m
      set ip=!ip: =!
      for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=^." %%n in ("!ip!") do set iprange=%%n.%%o
     if !iprange! == !range! set ipaddress=!ip!
   )
)
echo !ipaddress!
```